# Passing a variable from one action to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a show action in my controller:

```
  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /postings/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
```

I also have another action in the same controller

```
  def dosomething
      @currentpost = ??
  end
```

How can I get a reference to the current shown post inside the dosomething action?

Comment: Would you like your app to show the post from a particular user?

Comment: not show it but get some variables such as the user's name and address

Comment: Okay so I assume there is some form of association between `User` and `Post`

Comment: I assume you have some kind of user authentication going on as well. If that's the case, can we take a look at your ApplicationController?

Comment: devise. and a post belongs to a user

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You say `dosomething` is an action. That means, it is called in a seperate HTTP request.

There are several methods to share data between requests:

- store in in the session
- store it in a hidden field of the form, if `dosomething` is the action of a form
- forward it as a parameter, if `dosomething` is called by a `link_to`
- if `dosomething` is an action for a `post` and all this is in the `PostsController` and you have a route to this action then:

in your show view use

```
<%= link_to 'do something', dosomething_post_path(@post) %>
```

and in your action

```
def dosomething
  @currentpost = Post.find(params[:id])
  ....
end
```

in your `routes.rb` you need something like

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    get 'dosomething'
  end
end
```

or with a form:
in your view:

```
<%= form_for @message, :url => {:action => "dosomething"}, :method => "post" do |f| %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag :post_id, @post.id %>
...
```

in your controller:

```
def dosomething
  @currentpost = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  ....
end
```

Comment: I believe Ayrad wants to be able to get some of the users attributes into his `dosomething` method. I believe all that your method would be doing is getting finding the post. But he want the `dosomething` method to reference the user.

Comment: yes David, do something sends an email to the the the shown post's user

Comment: how do you want to initiate the sending of the email? How is `dosomething` called?

Comment: from a form in the show page 
<%= form_for @message, :url => {:action => "dosomething"}, :method => "post" do |f| %>

Comment: I added an example for hidden field

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your required variable from `controller` to `view` first. It means from `show` action you have to pass variable to it's `view`. From that `view` you have to hit or call `dosomthing` action with this variable.

You can hit/call this `dosomthing` action by **ajax** request or by submitting **form** from a `view`.